# mvc5 aspx file as partial and added to controller view, how to secure aspx files based on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

currently MVC5(.cshtml) it not supporting report viewers directly for that what id id is:

```
1- created .aspx file and prepared all the report in side
2- called the .aspx file in mvc5 controller as partial and included rdlc
```

now i want to

> secure any aspx file, if some one know direct path for the aspx file
>   they can access directly

so how i can prevent it role based in mvc5

thanks in advance